# Как в скрипте изменяющем ширину блоков по большему к результату добавить +1px

Tags: jquery

Есть следующий скрипт изменяющий ширину определенных блоков на странице по большему:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var mw = 0;
   $('.megablock').each(function () {
       var w_block = parseInt($(this).width());
       if(w_block > mw) {
          mw = w_block;
       };
   });
   $('.megablock').width(mw);
});
```

Скрипт срабатывает, ширина блоков получается одинаковая, но проблема в том что скрипт округляет ширину в меньшую сторону. Например ширина большего блока 151,344px, после того как срабатывает скрипт ширина становится 151px из-за этого едет верстка, лучше бы было 152px

Как в скрипте добавить прибавление 1px к финальному результату или сделать округление до целого числа в большую сторону? Как решение этой задачи оформить в виде скрипта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В javascript есть библиотека математических функций `Math`, которая содержит функцию `ceil()` — округление чисел с плавающей запятой (`float`, `double`) в большую сторону, попробуйте, должно помочь.

```
Math.ceil(5.1); // 6
Math.ceil(5.9); // 6
```

Comment: А куда добавить эту функцию, и как правильно синтаксически записать? Как это оформить в виде скрипта?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить строку `var w_block = parseInt($(this).width());` на строку `var w_block = Math.ceil($(this).width());`

Comment: не срабатывает.. ширину всех элементов скрипт продолжает изменять по большему, но не округляет в большую сторону т.е. фактически ширина у большего 155.344px после того как скрипт срабатывает становится 155px, а надо 156px

Comment: Вот ваш код, попробуйте (в хроме по крайней мере) по очереди комментировать то одну строку то другую - разницу видно, у меня всё округляется в бОльшую сторону: https://jsfiddle.net/geoo1d2c/1/

Comment: В приведенном примере комментируя строчки действительно видно разницу. базовую ширину самого широкого элемента в 143.141px  (без border) превращает в 144px (для всех элементов) т.е. что и требуется, почему у меня не работает сейчас буду разбираться.. Спасибо!

Comment: К сожалению так и не получилось решить этот вопрос, предложенное evva решение 100% рабочее, но у меня не срабатывает по видимому что-то мешает (у меня .megablock обрабатывают еще и другие скрипты, наверно дело в этом ), пока разобрался только в том как решить задачу по изначально поставленному вопросу, как добавить +1px к финальному результату в строке `$('.megablock').width(mw+1);` добавил +1 и все заработало, пиксель прибавился.. Вопрос задавал, так как не знал синтаксиса как правильно приплюсовать px, сейчас разобрался.. Спасибо за помощь!